# Get generic type using GetType

Tags: c#, generics, gettype

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class MyView<TPresenter> : UserControl, IMyView<TPresenter> where TPresenter : IPresenter
{
}
```

and a derived class:

```
public partial class CreateUserViewControl : MyView<CreateUserPresenter>
{
}
```

Now I want to get the `CreateUserViewControl`'s generic type (name) from all types in assembly, like this:

```
var genericType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t == typeof(MyView<>)).First().GetGenericArguments().First();
```

I would expect that `genericType` would contain `CreateUserViewControl` type but instead it contains `TPresenter`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get `CreateUserViewControl` type?

EDIT:

Ok, after a short review of my own question, I see, where the reason lies.
It's the `t == typeof(MyView<>)` comparison part. I realized that the only type which is going to be returned from that check is the abstract class.

What I want to do is to check if `typeof(MyView<>).IsAssignableFrom(t)` but unfortunately this doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you want the inspect the `CreateUserViewControl` type, why does your `Where()` query look for the base class instead? Your code isn't making much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should compare `t.BaseType` and `MyView<>`, because current type is not a generic type, but his parent can be. It's similar to the code below

```
    var genericBaseType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyView<>)).First();
    var genericArgument = genericBaseType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().First();
```

Comment: That did the job, thanks. Except that I had to use `typeof(MyView<>)` instead of `typeof(MyView<><>)`.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateUserViewControl` *isn't generic* and so doesn't have any generic arguments.  It inherits from a generic class, and the generic class it inherits from has a generic argument of `CreateUserViewControl`.

Your code only gets the type for the one specific class, `MyView<TPresenter>`, which is what you get the result for, because you only get types that are equal to that one type; nothing else *can* be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't exactly trivial, but it's not terribly difficult.  What you have to do is enumerate the base types of a given type and check if each of them is some concrete version of `MyView<T>`.

Here's a helper that'll enumerate the base types of a given type.

```
internal static class TypeEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetBaseTypes( this Type type )
    {
        yield return type;

        while( type.BaseType != null )
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have that you can create another method to check if a type inherits from `MyView`:

```
public static bool InheritsMyView( Type type, out Type genericArgument )
{
    foreach( var baseType in type.GetBaseTypes() )
    {
        if( !baseType.IsGenericType ) continue;
        if( baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof( MyView<> ) ) continue;
        genericArgument = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        return true;
    }

    genericArgument = null;
    return false;
}
```